# JBoss 7.1 with Hibernate 4.3.5

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, jboss

Ich need to use Hibernate 4.3.5. But my Jboss has provided Hibernate 4.0.1, which i don't need. I configured my pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Alpha3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Alpha3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But i noticed it that my jboss deploys still with Hibernate 4.0.1. If i check my dependencies in Eclipse, Eclipse told me: Hibernate-core: 4.3.5 Final[compile] managed: 4.2.0 CR1. What does "managed" here mean? How can i configure my jboss that it deploys with the newest Hibernate version?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to update the corresponding modules in your jboss 7 server installation.
After backing up your current hibernate modules copy the relevant modules downloaded from the hibernate site into the corresponding places under /modules/org/hibernate/... , then edit the respective module.xml files that they point to the new hibernate jars.